# How to unzip a .gz file using Git Bash on Windows?

Tags: linux, git-bash, unzip

I have tried to open a `.gz` file, How can i proceed ?

```
Ex: filename=details_IMST_20180626210209.dat.gz
```

Tried to open with **notepad**, git bash using `less` command. But couldn't open as it is zipped. suggest way to open the file.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This has been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer: [How to unzip a .gz file on Windows](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+unzip+a+.gz+file+on+Windows). Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to the file location in Git Bash and run the below command.

```
$ gunzip details_IMST_20180626210209.dat.gz
```

After executing that command, `details_IMST_20180626210209.dat` got created
(`.gz` was removed).

We can open that file from **notepad/notepad++**.